# When should one use list slice for whole list assignment?

Tags: python, slice

In python we know A[:] is a copy of list A.
There seems to be two ways to update a list A in Python.

```
A = [1, 2] #id(A)=140040769748648
A[:] = [2, 3] #id(A)=140040769748648
A = [2, 3] #id(A)=140040772477512
```

As you can see using slice annotation for list assignment retains the list address in memory while direct assignment does not.
But my question is when would it be more useful to use one over the other?

Comment: The only reason you'd need to assign to a slice like that is if you want the changes to be visible to other places in the code that already have a reference to the existing list.  Simple assignment would otherwise be more efficient.

Comment: @mkrieger1: exactly what I am looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`x[:] = y` is a copying assignment. This means that it'll copy the list you assign:

```py
x = [1, 2]
y = [3, 4]
x[:] = y
y[0] = 10
x # [3, 4]
  thrown in php shell code on line 1
y # [10, 4]
```

whereas `x = y` doesn't copy:

```py
x = [1, 2]
y = [3, 4]
x = y
y[0] = 10
x # [10, 4] note how this has changed also
y # [10, 4]
```

So, `x[:] = y` is slower (due to making a copy), but if you plan on mutating the list later and don't want `x` to change, then use it. You could alternatively write it `x = y[:]`, but `x[:] = y` has the benefit of being able to assign any iterable to `x`, not just lists. Note that `x[:] = y` also modifies the list in place, leading to different behavior (such as when passing the list to a function):

```py
def mutate(l):
    l[:] = [1, 2, 3]

x = [4, 5]
mutate(x)
x # [1, 2, 3]
```

`x` would remain `[4, 5]` if you used `l = [1, 2, 3]` instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a reference to the list somewhere else, then the [:] retains those changes, where as setting it directly will not.

```
def foo():
  a = ['1', '2']

  bar(a)

  print(a)  # ['3', '4']

def bar(arr):
  arr[:] = ['3', '4']
```

Can be useful for things like `os.walk`

```
depth = 0
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(...):
   if depth = 3:
      # stop walking after a depth of 3
      dirs[:] = []

   depth += 1
```

In this instance, assigning dirs a new array wouldn't do it.  You have to change the original.